# Find out where custom PHP function is defined

Tags: php, function, exists

I use internal function `function_exists`, that can return `true` but I can't find the custom function in my project. I also debugged my code to trace the function, but the debugger does not step into my custom function. I very look forward to know why. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask], it is unclear what you are asking. Is your problem that you are trying to overwrite a function inside an `if(function_exists())`, but it never happens, because the function already exists _somewhere_? Well then simply _remove_ the condition, _don't_ check if the function exists before you redeclare it - then you will get an error message _telling_ you where that function was declared first, file and line number ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out where is the function defined, use following code:

```
<?php
   $rf = new ReflectionFunction('my_fuction_name');
   echo 'file:' . $rf->getFileName() . ', line:' . $rf->getStartLine();
?>
```

Please note that if the function is not defined in source code, but it's internal PHP function, both `getFileName()` and `getStartLine()` will return `false`.

You can check if the function is internal that way:

```
<?php
   $rf = new ReflectionFunction('my_fuction_name');
   if($rf->isInternal() === TRUE){
      echo "Function is internal!";
   }else{
      echo "Function is not internal.";
   }
?>
```